# Can someone please explain me this code?

Tags: c

Can someone please explain me the concept of `[\]` here?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int f(int t[\]){
    return t[0\] + t[2\];
}

int main(void){
    int i,a[\] = {-2,-1,0,1,2};
    i = f(a+2);
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is '\' in int t[ \ ]?

Comment: are you able to compile this code ?

Comment: @Pac0 I was attempting an assessment and I chose the option "The compilation fails"  but the answer was incorrect.

Comment: Well, I would *guess* that this assessment was "badly copied", and some backslashes were apparently mistakenly added before any `]`  character. The `\\` backslash is often use to "*escape*" some special characters.  Is this assessment an official thing ? or more like a website that collects some copies / dumps ?

Comment: I’ve seen this before, the `\]` is a typesetting error in the document (I’m guessing a PDF).  Remove that backslash before the closing bracket and the code should compile correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason for `'\'` in your C code. Maybe it is some leftover from copying the code since it is consistently proceeding  the `]` closing brackets.

If you remove `'\'` from your program it will compile and the function `f(a+2)`
will give you the sum of `third` and `fifth` element in the array `a[]`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int f(int t[])
{
    return t[0] + t[2];
}

int main(void){
    int i,a[] = {-2,-1,0,1,2};

    i = f(a+2); // (a+2) -> { 0, 1, 2 }

    printf("%d",i); 

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2
```